# Biggest $(-t,t)\subset A-A$ if $λ(Α)>0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve a problem which  states that if $λ(E)>1$ ($λ$ being the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$) then there exists $x,y \in E$ such that $x\neq y $ and $ x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

From the proof of the Steinhaus Lemma we can see that  $λ(Ε)>0\Rightarrow (-\frac{λ(Ε)}{2},\frac{λ(Ε)}{2})\in E-E$ and so it's trivial to solve the excerise.

I was wondering if we can improve the size of the interval contained in the difference set or is this the best we can hope for in general.

Comment: The statement is incoherent. What does "if $\lambda(E)$" mean? Whatever that means, we don't need to assume it to show that there exist $x,y$ with $x\ne y$ and $x-y\in\Bbb Z$; just let $x=1$, $y=0$.

Comment: You are right, the post didn't make much sense. I hope it's better now.

Comment: It would be better if you required $x,y$ to belong to $E$!

Comment: Added that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear that the result you state is sharp. Let $E=(0,1)$; then $\lambda(E)=1$ but there do not exist $x,y\in E$ with $x\ne y$ and $x-y\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Of course, now you say it , it seems obvious... Thanks !